# Implicit conversion of java.util.List to scala List does not occur

Tags: java, scala, implicit-conversion, scala-java-interop

I have very basic problem with scala.collection.JavaConversions. I would expect that following code would work but implicit conversion from java.util.List[String] to scala List[String] does not happen. Why?

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util
class Test {
  def getStrings() : List[String] = {
    val results : java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
    results
  }
}
```

I get following message from compi

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[String]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.List[String]
    results
    ^
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Convert it to:

```
def getStrings() : Seq[String] = {
    val results : java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
    results
  }
```

This is because, the implicit function for the conversion is defined as:

```
implicit def asScalaBuffer[A](l: java.util.List[A]): mutable.Buffer[A]
```

It returns a `mutable.Buffer` and not `scala.collection.immutable.List`. Hence the error. So alternative is to use a `Seq` instead of `List` or convert it to a `immutable.List` as below:

```
def getStrings() : List[String] = {
    val results = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()     
    results.toList
}
```

Comment: You don't need `: java.util.List[String]` in the first case.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it is only showed for explanation where it is converted.

Answer (score 14):

All you need to do is to import this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```